# element size influencing C# collection performance?

Tags: c#, performance, collections, clr

Given the task to improve the performance of a piece of code, I have came across the following phenomenon. I have a large collection of reference types in a generic Queue and I'm removing and processing the element one by one, then add them to another generic collection.

It seems the larger the elements are the more time it takes to add the element to the collection.

Trying to narrow down the problem to the relevant part of the code, I've written a test (omitting the processing of elements, just doing the insert):

```
    class Small 
    {
        public Small()
        {
            this.s001 = "001";
            this.s002 = "002";
        }
        string s001;
        string s002;
    }


    class Large
    {
        public Large()
        {
            this.s001 = "001";
            this.s002 = "002";
            ...
            this.s050 = "050";

        }
        string s001;
        string s002;
        ...
        string s050;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int N = 1000000;
        var storage = new List<object>(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            //storage.Add(new Small());
            storage.Add(new Large());
        }

        List<object> outCollection = new List<object>();
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = N-1; i > 0; --i)
        {          
            outCollection.Add(storage[i];);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

On the test machine, using the Small class, it takes about 25-30 ms to run, while it takes 40-45 ms with Large. 
I know that the outCollection has to grow from time to time to be able to store all the items, so there is some dynamic memory allocation. But given an initial collection size even makes the difference more obvious: 11-12 ms with Small and 35-38 ms with Large objects.

I am somewhat surprised, as these are reference types, so I was expecting the collections to work only with references to the Small/Large instances. I have read Eric Lippert's relevant [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses/) that and know that references should not be treated as pointers. At the same time, AFAIK currently they are implemented as pointers and their size and the collection's performance should be independent of element size.

I've decided to put up a question here hoping that someone could explain or help me to understand what's happening here. Aside the performance improvement, I'm really curious what is happening behind the scenes.

Update:
Profiling data using the diagnostic tools didn't help me much, although I have to admit I'm not an expert using the profiler. I'll collect more data later today to find where the bottleneck is.

The pressure on the GC is quite high of course, especially with the `Large` instances. But once the instances are created and stored in the `storage` collection, and the program enters the loop, there was no collection triggered any more, and memory usage hasn't increased significantly (`outCollction` already pre-allocated).

Most of the CPU time is of course spent with memory allocation (JIT_New), around 62% and the only other significant entry is Function Name  Inclusive Samples   Exclusive Samples   Inclusive Samples % Exclusive Samples % Module Name
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.__Canon].Add with about 7%.

With 1 million items the preallocated `outCollection` size is 8 million bytes (the same as the size of `storage`); one can suspect 64 bit addresses being stored in the collections.

Probably I'm not using the tools properly or don't have the experience to interpret the results correctly, but the profiler didn't help me to get closer to the cause. 
If the loop is not triggering collections and it only copies pointers between 2 pre-allocated collections, how could the item size cause any difference? Cache hit/miss ratio is supposed to be the more or less the same in both cases, as the loop is iteration over a list of "addresses" in both cases.

Thanks for all the help so far, I will collect more data, and put an update here if anything found.

Comment: What facts have we gathered using visual studios diagnostic tools?

Comment: Reading your code it occurs to me that you are inserting newly created elements into your lists. Creating an element necessarily runs the constructor, and the ``Small`` class initializes two fields, while the ``Large`` class initializes 50 fields in the constructor, which is a good reason for seeing a difference.

Comment: @D.Foley: I don't have the proper permissions on the box I'm working on at the moment, but I'll update my post with diagnostic data when I can run the profiler.
@dumetrulo: if you check the code, you can see that only the `storage` collection is filled with newly created elements, and that part is not included in the measurement. By the time the items are added to the `outCollection` the memory is already allocated and the constructors have initialized the instances.

Comment: **Use a profiler to answer performance questions**. Asking people on the internet to guess what makes a program slow is *guessing*. Use *science* to answer this empirical engineering question.

Comment: If asked to guess, my first thoughts would be (1) cache misses, and (2) collection pressure. Those are hypotheses that could be wrong; **test them**.

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that at least one action in the above (maybe some type checks) will require a de-reference. Then the fact that many `Small`s are probably sat close together on the heap and thus sharing cache lines could account for some amount of difference (certainly many more of them could share a single cache line than `Large`s).

Added to which you are also accessing them in the reverse order in which they were allocated which maximises such a benefit.

Comment: @Damien_The_Uneliever: thanks, the argument about the cache makes sense, obviously more `Small` instances can fit into the cache than `Large`s. I'll try to find a method to verify if it's causing the difference.
Going through the storage in reverse order is something that remained there from the original code. Going the opposite direction doesn't make much difference (maybe 1-2 ms slower), but there is more deviation from the average.

Comment: @LittlePilgrim - either direction still means that each successive item you access was the one allocated before/after the previous one and so we expect them to be roughly colocated.